# The complicated choice with socks

Tags: logical-deduction, mathematics

You are about to leave for holiday, but you forgot socks! You race back to your room, but all the lights are off, so you can't see the color of the socks.

Never mind, because you remember that in your drawer there are ten pairs of white socks, ten pairs of black socks, and eleven pairs of blue socks, but they are all mixed up.

How many of your socks do you need to take before you can be sure to have at least one matching pair?

Comment: I normally pair my socks together before hand with the *lights on*.....so I would only ever need to take 1 pair (2 socks)...Maybe I'm just weird like that though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take four socks.

Worse case scenario, the first three socks are from different color. The fourth must coincide with one of the first three.